# Swift Package Manager - Storyboard bundle

Tags: storyboard, bundle, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to add support for SPM in one of our projects that has storyboards.

Currently we grab it `UIStoryboard(name: String, bundle: String?)` but this doesn't seem to work with SPM, as there isn't really a bundle. Even printing all the bundles doesn't show the bundle of our package.

Any way we can support storyboards or are SPM's meant to be just files?

Attempts:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "GiftCards", bundle: Bundle(for: self))
UIStoryboard(name: "GiftCards", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
UIStoryboard(name: "GiftCards", bundle: Bundle(identifier: "com.x.x"))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the key thing is to use Bundle.module when instantiating the storyboard

1- Add this view controller extension to the swift package:

```
 public extension UIViewController{
        
        public static func getStoryboardVC() -> UIViewController { 
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: self), bundle: Bundle.module) // Use Bundle.module
            return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        }
 }
```

The Bundle.module represents the containing package.

2- In the app, in my case the swift package is called MySwiftPackage. I call that extension method from the swift package to instantiate the view controller I want to present:

```
   @IBAction func openCard(){
        let vc = MySwiftPackage.MyViewController.getStoryboardVC() as! MySwiftPackage.MyViewController
        vc.personNo = "11111"
        vc.personId = "8888888"
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this will work too! We chose to keep the code changes isolated to the main app, in the initializer of the `AppDelegate` (my answer is now edited to show this). Hopefully Apple will improve this in the future and we can avoid either workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

*Update: XCode 14.2 (and perhaps earlier) does not require any of the steps below. Storyboards in the packages are automagically loaded as needed. Thanks to the answer by @derpoliuk for pointing this out and providing a GitHub example.*

As of Xcode 12.0 this sort of works, but needs a few extra steps to complete it.

### Scenario:

- an app that shows an embedded storyboard from a package named `BadgeKit`
- a Swift package named `BadgeKit` with `Package.swift` header `// swift-tools-version:5.3` or higher
- a storyboard in BadgeKit called `BadgeKit.storyboard`

### Goal:

- Add a storyboard reference in an app storyboard and make it work in the app

### Steps:

#### Add the storyboard reference to the app storyboard and configure it as follows:

[image: Storyboard Reference property panel with Storyboard value "BadgeKit" and Bundle identifier "BadgeKit-BadgeKit-resources"]

Storyboard Reference property panel with Storyboard value `BadgeKit` and Bundle identifier `BadgeKit-BadgeKit-resources`.

Xcode automatically generates a bundle (and its identifier) for you to hold resources found in an SPM package using the following format: `[package name]-[package target name]-resources`. In our case the package name and target name are the same (`BadgeKit`).

While SPM resource bundles are always created and included in the app during the build process, they are not automatically available at runtime *outside* the package. If you aren't importing and using a package's target anywhere in your code, Xcode tries to optimize by not loading that package's resource bundle (it is probably an oversight on Apple's part that storyboard references alone aren't enough to trigger this). So a workaround is needed to trick Xcode into making an SPM package's bundle available if you are only using its resources in a storyboard.

#### Add this code to the app's `AppDelegate.swift` file as a workaround:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain final class AppDelegate: UIResponder {

    […]

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        // WORKAROUND: Storyboards do not trigger the loading of resource bundles in Swift Packages.
        let bundleNames = ["BadgeKit_BadgeKit"]
        bundleNames.forEach { (bundleName) in
            guard
                let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: bundleName, withExtension: "bundle"),
                let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) else {
                preconditionFailure()
            }
            bundle.load()
        }

        […]
    }

    […]

}
```

In our example, the array `bundleNames` contains a single string that correspond to the expected *filename* of the bundle our package will create for its resources during the build process. Xcode automatically names these bundle files as follows: `[package name]_[package target name].bundle`. Note that a bundle's *filename* is not the same as its *identifier*.

If you are curious about which bundles (and their corresponding identifiers) are loaded and available at runtime, you can use the following code to troubleshoot:

```swift
let bundles = Bundle.allBundles
bundles.forEach { (bundle) in
    print("Bundle identifier loaded: \(bundle.bundleIdentifier)") }
}
```

#### Configure the storyboard in the SPM BadgeKit package:

- Fill in “Module” with the SPM package target name ("BadgeKit")
- Uncheck “Inherit Module from Target”

[image: Storyboard property panel with Module value BadgeKit]

Comment: omg, it worked! only `let _=` in the app delegate should be `let bundle =` How did you know this stuff???

Comment: Thanks for that correction @fullmoon. Typo is now fixed. Full credit to user salutis for working this out originally.

Comment: Awesome! actually it also worked using another way. Key thing is using `Bundle.module` in the package to instantiate the storyboard view controller. I added a new answer if you'd like to check.

Comment: I get "Could not find a storyboard named" ... and it's still looking in my main .app not in the Bundle I specified... ...  I'm AM using the package target in other parts of the code....must be a timing issue.....  Adding the workaround fixed it.

Comment: Any ideas why it stops working when the build is created for the App Store or as an .ipa file?

Comment: @fullmoon fwiw it is working ok for me in .ipa files and in the App Store. Do you have the loading workaround in the AppDelegate (as shown above)?

Comment: @mm2001 Yes I implemented the workaround as well as the other way. Both work perfect when building from Xcode to device, but exporting as .ipa will generate this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'ARCameraVC' in bundle NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../MyIDCardAppClip.app> (loaded)' ` It didn't consider the `let bundleNames = ["ARMap_ARMap"]` I declared in the appDelegate following the workaround.

Comment: I solved it with the magic of starting fresh :) hehe. I was using the SP with an App Clip. All I did was  I deleted the App Clip and created it again and linked the SP then it worked in .ipa and the App Store reviewers didn't complain.

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 13 both top-rated answers are partially helpful ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64006032/1226304) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805770/1226304)), so I decided to put summary together.

#### To make storyboards work in Swift Package, you need to:

1. In your storyboard manually select `Module` for your view controller:

   [image: View Controller's Module]
2. Pass `Bundle.module` when creating a storyboard:

   ```swift
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.module)
   return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
   ```

#### Example:

I created a simple example for this on GitHub: https://github.com/derpoliuk/swift-module-storyboard

Answer (score 3):

starting on Swift 5.3, thanks to [SE-0271](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md), you can add bundle resources on swift package manager by adding `resources` on your `.target` declaration.

example:

```
.target(
   name: "HelloWorldProgram",
   dependencies: [], 
   resources: [.process(Images), .process("README.md")]
)
```

if you want to learn more, I have written an article on [medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593), discussing this topic

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not currently supported with SwiftPM. There is a proposal in the works [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-pm-bundles-and-resources/).