# How to use storyboard reference segue when required storyboard is in Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, swift-package-manager

Im using a swift package which has textfield xib, some storyboards as resources. My question here is I'm trying to present a viewController through segue which is in swift Package. In storyboard reference I have given the storyBoard name "Login" and given the Bundle as "Sample". while calling performSegue Im getting crash saying that Login storyboard not present in NSBundle. it automatically taking the NSBundle not the Sample_Sample.module. How to solve this?

[image: Storyboard reference]

[image: Crash error]

Comment: Have you made sure that the VC in the swift package has the current target you are working in?

Comment: See if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622492/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named/23622657

Comment: @VisalRajapakse I have given `Sample` as Module name and unchecked **Inherit from Module Target** in Swift Package Storyboard. still getting crash.

Comment: This answer seemed to solve it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000140/swift-package-manager-storyboard-bundle